# Link dll to static library and load it into an application linked against the same static library

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am creating an application that supports modules in the form of dlls that are loaded dynamically at runtime. The code is laid out in the following way:

- **core** - static library

  This has a mechanism to load shared libraries and call a "create" function that returns a new Module object (uses a shared header).
- **module** shared library (linked against core static library)

  This module uses the shared Module header and also uses other classes from the core library (hence why it is linked against the core library). It is built to include all symbols from static libraries.
- **test application** executable (linked against core static library)

I am getting funky, and seemingly sporadic behavior. They always end up in access violations but it seems that member variables that I very explicitly set (integers) will print out in later functions as garbage (i have verified that they are not being deleted earlier). This only ever seems to happen if they dynamic library is loaded (even if I never call the create function).

My main question is, is there are danger here that the symbols in the shared library will conflict with the symbols in the executable (since they came from the same static library) and cause problems even though they are from the exact same static library?

Comment: I am currently seeing this on OS X, but it also compiles on Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows. I will try this on Linux now to see if the same thing is happening.

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind to better diagnose it.

Comment: Does the core library use anything that could not be duplicated such as named files or devices?

Comment: No, the core library is completely self contained. It seems that the problem was that I wasn't compiling the core library as Position Independent Code. All the files had the -fPIC argument but the static library did not. This caused an error on Linux but not on OS X. I don't completely understand how that caused the manifestation I was seeing so I am holding off on answering my own question for now in case someone else cares to explain it better. (also, I am waiting to make sure I don't see the problem again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak for Linux and OS X behavior, but on Windows, the following is exactly what is happening. Since you say you also want to compile on Windows, this is relevant.

The problem you are experiencing is that **you actually have multiple versions of everything in the core**. Each module and the application itself has its own copy of the core, and their variables are **not** shared. This includes the C runtime, so things like new/delete across module boundaries are fraught with peril.

To verify that this is what is happening, create a simple test: set a global in the core to a value in your test application, then from *from your dynamically loaded code* try to access that global and see what you get. I will wager that you will see that your store to the global will not be reflected!

Solutions:

1) Make core a shared dynamic library. This may or may not be an option for you.

2) Operate extremely carefully with the knowledge of the above; All CRT and/or your own core state will not be shared, so you must make sure things will be allocated/destroyed on their own side of the module boundaries, among other things.

My own application is designed almost identically to yours; ie a static library with shared code needed by both the application and the modules, and then dynamically loaded plugins loaded by the application core.

What I do for all shared core state that must be accessed across modules is that the first thing each module does after loading is have its "core pointer" set to an instantiation of the core libraries in the application. This ensures that all modules are working with the same data.